# Manejo de rol o status en variables de sesión - PHP

Tags: php, sesiones

Tengo mis páginas creadas con extension **.php** de forma tal que utilizo ***includes*** para así poder estructurar el sitio y la lógica de negocio.

En el caso del menú tengo 3:

1. Cuando no se ha ingresado al sistema.
2. Cuando se ha ingresado al sistema como usuario *normal (privilegios mínimos)*.
3. Cuando se ha ingresado al sistema como *administrador (mayor número de privilegios)*.

Anexo la consulta asociada a este proceso:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre,email,password,tipo_cuenta FROM usuario WHERE email='$correo'";

$consul=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$fila=mysqli_num_rows($consul);

if ($fila>0) {
    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consul);
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$data["nombre"];
    //guardo el nombre del usuario
    $_SESSION['rol']=$data['tipo_cuenta'];
    //guardo el rol , si es administrador o normal
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

> Ahora en el `index` necesito comprobar si el rol efectivamente es de tipo normal o de tipo administrador.

A continuación les muestro el `index`:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['rol']=="administrador"){

    include("secciones/seccion_header_admin.php");

}else if($_SESSION['rol']=="normal"){

    include("secciones/seccion_header_log.php");

}else{
    include("secciones/seccion_header.php");
}
?>
```

El problema radica en que al realizar el proceso de inicio de sesión, bien sea como *admin* o como *usuario normal*, siempre me muestra el menú asociado al usuario normal, es decir, el panel de administración, nunca lo muestra.

¿Por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Tal parece que tu código está bien planteado. Tendrías que chequear si no estás sobreescribiendo `$_SESSION['rol']` antes de llegar a los if o revisar que en tu base de datos "tipo_cuenta" tenga efectivamente para administrador como valor "administrador" puede que lo que esté dentro de la base de datos no sea igual a la comparación en tu if. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: gracias Huskie. si sirve de ayuda para otras personas lo que hice para solucionarlo fue ir a mi base de datos y crear otro campo al cual he llamado "admin" y en vez de que fuera un string le he dicho que sea de tipo boolean , así si es admin sera 1 y si no lo es 2 . haciendo el mismo if que tengo arriba me funciono a la perfección.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que pudiste solucionarlo! Te sugeriria que lo coloques como respesta aquí en tu misma pregunta. Así otras personas también se guian cuando tengan una duda similar a la tuya. Un saludo.

Comment: Como observación adicional te digo que trates en tu tiempo libre de intentar que funcione sin booleano, con character varying por ejemplo. Por qué? pues porque un sistema o sitio más complejo que te toque desarrollar en un futuro probablemente requerirá más de dos roles y el campo booleano maneja eso, sólo dos valores o roles.

Comment: Normalmente lo que se hace es que se coloca un campo llamado "status" por ejemplo de tipo character (y no character vaying) de longitud "1". Entonces si es administrador el valor guardado es "A", si es usuario común es "U", si es dueño es "D". Es a manera de ejemplo para ampliarte un poco como podrías hacerlo cuando necesites más de dos roles. Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo